# how to generate cross button(&times) through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following doesn't generate a 'cross' or (X) in the browser.

```
closeLink.text("&times;");
```

What should be set here to display the 'X' mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&times;` is an HTML entity.
You can either set the element's HTML (not text) to HTML source with that entity, or set the text directly by passing ×.

Comment: closeLink.html("&times;"); is working in jQuery/jLite. Nice !!

Comment: is it possible to send x to the method? what should be the code for this ?

Comment: @user2599052: Javascript string literals can have arbitrary Unicode characters.  You can just write that.

Answer (score 0):

For those who found this but are not using jQuery:

```
closeLink.innerHTML = '&times;'
```